# Postgresql update with string_agg

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables say table 1 and table 2. I need to match the two tables with Party ID. If the party id matched and domain which is also matched then no need to update anything in an invalid email column. In case if party id matched and the domain is not matched with table 1 then update all the domain with comma-separated in the invalid column

[image: re]

Anyone help me on this.....!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
update table2
  set invalid_email=array_to_string(t1.domaines,';') 
  from (select party_id,array_agg(domaine) as domaines from table1 group by party_id) t1 
 where table2.party_id=t1.party_id and table2.domaine not in (select unnest(domaines))
```